# MVC 3 Razor Syntax for straight text output?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Using Razor how/can you write straight text with out wrapping it in some type of html tag?

Example (This works but adds extra span tags):

```
@{ var foo = true; }
@if(foo) { <span>Yes</span> } else { <span>No</span> }
```

I'd like to keep my final markup as clean as possible and not have the extra tags.

Thanks!

Answer (score 134, accepted):

use the **[`<text>`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx)** tags

```
@{ var foo = true; }
@if(foo) { <text>Yes</text> } else { <text>No</text> }
```

The `<text>` tag signals to the razor view engine to write the contents to the output.

Alternatively, you can use `@:`

```
@{ var foo = true; }
@if(foo) { @:Yes } else { @:No }
```

Comment: Hey Russ, with the second example (@:), I copied the code to the bottom of one of my views, and I'm getting an exception, however if I use the text tags, it works, any thoughts? (Exception to follow)

Comment: The if block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Line 48: @{ var foo = true; }
Line 49: @if(foo) { @:Yes } else { @:No }

Comment: If you put the `@:Yes` and `@:No` on separate lines, all is well. I think the syntax parser is interpreting everything following `@:Yes...` to be text when on a single line, hence the opening brace of `@if (foo) {...` is unmatched.

Answer (score 15):

A point worth to be noted here:

@: can be used only inside an @

(in case any body like me is wondering why @: does not work!)

Comment: Useful related link: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax

Comment: @Bounty But outside it why would you need, you can just write plane Text

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying like I am to inject data into Javascript I found this to work.

```
@Html.Raw(table)
```

I was pulling data from a database and injecting it into the code for a Google chart.

So in the OP's case,

```
@if (foo) { Html.Raw("Yes") } else { Html.Raw("No") }
```