# MVC: How to render content of .js file into script tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to "load" the content of my .js file inside the script tags. However when I do `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/d3TestBundle.js")` the page loads the script but does not insert the code inside the script tag.

```
<svg width="960" height="500">
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/d3TestBundle.js")
</svg>
```

This gives me:
[image: Html equivalent]

How can I render the content of my .js file as bellow:

```
<svg width="960" height="500">
    <script>
        (myfunction(d3){
            //my code
            //my code
        }
    </script>
</svg>
```

Comment: Read file into String, then echo the String.

Comment: @ChrisG I have successfully read the file into string[], but how should I insert the text into the script tag without it being in text format and functional as script?

Comment: It's just text though. Output it as text and it will be functional.

Comment: I manage to work it out by putting each line in a text tag(made by `@foreach (var line in text)`) inside a script tag

Comment: Yeah, you need to output the `<script>` tag, then the text, then the closing `</script>`.

Comment: @ChrisG So how do I make your comment the solution? (new to stackoverflow; can I make a comment the solution?)

Comment: Is this question essentially a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451396/mvc-3-razor-syntax-for-straight-text-output?

Comment: @ChrisG No, I meant I wanted to make your comment the answer to my question. Since you did not "answer" my question, but added a comment to my question I see no way of how I can mark my question as Solved(have it being green instead of gray). As it is now won't the question be marked as unresolved?

Comment: My problem with this question is that it currently reads as if based on the wrong assumption that outputting the text of a .js file into a template is different from outputting any other text into a template. So my question is whether this question is a useful addition to this website or not. That's why I haven't posted an answer but a comment.

Comment: @ChrisG I can agree with that. I support your decision.